# how to allow delete only if user is admin in php

Tags: php, mysql

how to allow delete if username is admin.

i want to allow delete only admin person to delete a record
please help me to fix this issue thanks......

session.php

```
<?php
// Establishing Connection with Server by passing server_name, user_id and password as a parameter
$connection = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "");
// Selecting Database
$db = mysql_select_db("dsrs", $connection);
session_start();// Starting Session
// Storing Session
$user_check=$_SESSION['login_user'];
// SQL Query To Fetch Complete Information Of User
$ses_sql=mysql_query("select username from admin where username='$user_check'", $connection);
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($ses_sql);
$login_session =$row['username'];
if(!isset($login_session)){
mysql_close($connection); // Closing Connection
header('Location: index.php'); // Redirecting To Home Page
}
?>
```

DELETE.PHP

```
<?php
/* 
 DELETE.PHP
 Deletes a specific entry from the 'drivers' table
*/

include('session.php');

 // connect to the database
 include('connect-db.php');

 // check if the 'id' variable is set in URL, and check that it is valid
 if (isset($_GET['id']) && is_numeric($_GET['id']))
 {
 // get id value
 $id = $_GET['id'];

 // delete the entry
 $result = mysql_query("DELETE FROM admission WHERE id=$id")
 or die(mysql_error()); 
 echo "<center>Delete.!</center>";
 }
?>
```

Comment: I presume you store the username of the currently logged in user in the session right? Why don't you say `if(USERNAME == 'admin') { RUN DELETE }`

Comment: yes where can i put this code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want is to only allow the `admin` users to delete the specified id.
I don't know how you set a user as an "admin", but this pseudo code will give you the general gist.

```
if (isset($_GET['id']) && is_numeric($_GET['id'])) {
    // get id value
    $id = $_GET['id'];

    // delete the entry if admin
    if($_SESSION['username'] == 'admin') {
        $result = mysql_query("DELETE FROM admission WHERE id=$id") or die(mysql_error()); 
        echo "<center>Delete.!</center>";
    }
 }
```

<sup>*I don't know what you store the username in the session as, so you'll need to change that.*</sup>

---

I'd suggest you stop using the `mysql_*` library as it is deprecated. You should look into [`PDO`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.pdo.php) and/or [`MySQLi Prepared Statements`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.mysqli.php).

Comment: i replace this code now this error is showing Notice: Undefined index: username in this line if($_SESSION['username'] == 'admin') {

Comment: Thats why I said you have to change that to the username that you get... @user1833487

Comment: oh ok i fix it but if user is not admin suppose then i want echo a msg you dont have permission to allow delete like that

Comment: ok thanks for help  but i am not a expert thats why i am asking